# JDBC in servlet

Tags: java, servlets, jdbc

I have a simple form to fetch data from `user` and store to database.

This is my simple form:

```jsp
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> Database Insertion Form </title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
<h1>
    <center> Phonebook</center>
</h1>
<Form method=post action="DbServlet">

    <pre>
        Surname: <input type="text" name="Surname">
        Forename: <input type="text" name="Forenames">
        Phone number: <input type="text" name="PhoneNum">
    </pre>
    <br><br>
    <center><input type="submit" VALUE="Commit"></center>
</Form>
</html>
```

And this is `DbServlet` Servlet:

```
@WebServlet("/DbServlet")
public class DbServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private PreparedStatement ps;
    private Connection connection;
    private String URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/lib";

    @Override
    public void init() throws ServletException {
        super.init();
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, "root", "2323");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {
            cnfe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response)
                                         throws IOException, ServletException {
        String surname, forenames, telNum;
        surname = request.getParameter("Surname");
        forenames = request.getParameter("Forenames");
        telNum = request.getParameter("PhoneNum");
        response.setContentType("text/HTML");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        out.println("<HTML>");
        out.println("<HEAD>");
        out.println("<TITLE>Servlet + JDBC</TITLE>");
        out.println("</HEAD>");
        out.println("<BODY>");
        String query = "INSERT INTO PhoneNums"
                + " VALUES('" + surname + "','"
                + forenames + "','" + telNum + "')";

        try {
            ps = connection.prepareStatement(query);
            ps.executeUpdate();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Done");
        } catch (SQLException sqle) {
            sqle.printStackTrace();
        }

        out.println("</BODY>");
        out.println("</HTML>");
        out.flush();
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        try {
            connection.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(
                    "Error on closing database!");
            ex.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

When I clicked to `submit` button in html form, nothing happens, even any exception!

MySQL connector jar file is present in the lib folder of Tomcat.

Comment: Are you submitting form with Post method?

Comment: You can look at the tomcat log files to find the missed exception

Comment: Is the `doPost()` method invoked properly, when you click the submit button given? Here is an invalid HTML mark up `<Form method=post action="DbServlet">`. `method=post` should be `method="post"` enclosed within quotes.

Comment: Could you please check (1)submit button reach to your doPostmethod(). (2) int result = ps.executeUpdate(); and print out this result is greater than 0.

Comment: OT: why do you use JOptionPane in a servlet ? That message should go to logging.

Comment: You are not actually putting anything in the body of the response. So you will get a blank page on success. Did you check if the database update succeeded, by accessing the database directly from PHPMyAdmin or any SQL client?

Comment: try opening the query with prepareStatement(sqlQuery,ResultSet.FORWARD_ONLY,ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);

Comment: Unrelated but: do ***not*** use `System.exit(1)` in a servlet. That will shutdown the whole Servlet container, not just your Servlet. Plus you can't use a Swing component (`JOptionPane`) in a Servlet. A Servlet has no UI (the server might no even have a graphical user interface)

Comment: @Sarz Yes, As you can see in `html` code.

Comment: Just a suggestion in your connection URL `"jdbc:mysql://localhost/lib"` if you are connecting to your localhost only you can directly write `"jdbc:mysql:///lib"`

Comment: @GPRathour that is a nice bit of trivia, but it is of course incredibly poor to have such connection details hardcoded to begin with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your form you have written `<Form method=post action="DbServlet">`

You have not written `""` (double quotes) with your method name (post) and I guess therefore post method has not been defined for the form and by default it is calling the `doGet()` method of your servlet rather than `doPost()`

So write it like,

`<form method="post" action="DbServlet">`

The second suggestion I would like to give is:

As you are using `PreparedStatement` in your code so there is no need to manage `'` single quotes your self for the query.

You can use `?` question mark in the query string and then later on use the `setXXX` methods like `setInt()` or `setString`

```
String query = "INSERT INTO PhoneNums  VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
ps = connection.prepareStatement(query);
ps.setString(1, surname);
ps.setString(2, forenames);
ps.setString(3, telNum);
ps.executeUpdate();


// I believe all these three are strings
```

Comment: @user3808021 But which one of the two given suggestions was the winner? Knowing that is very relevant information to wrap up this question. Not for you, for others who come here looking for an answer to the same problem.

Comment: @Gimby You right, The first Solution solved my problem.

Comment: @Gimby Thanks for mentioning the points. It is also a good practice to upvote good answers. :p ;)

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to commit the update:

```
connection.commit();
```

as the destroy (and connection.close()) is called when the servlet get out of service (maybe never).

Comment: I believe connection is by default auto commit.

Comment: He doesnt need commit since he is not using transactions